# Pass field from Droid project to PCL, Xamarin.Forms

Tags: facebook-graph-api, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I have an app that allows users to log in via facebook, once user enters their credentials - My api request saves the user onto the database and auto-generates a user token(This is unique to each user). In order to display user specific details once user logs in - the token needs to be referenced. I am trying to get this token to the PCL project but it returns null just for the token. When I tried passing another string like name, it passes the correct value. Any help  will be much appreciated.Thanks

**FacebookRender in droid:**

```
 public class FacebookRender : PageRenderer
    {
        public FacebookRender()
        {
            CustomerService customerService = new CustomerService();
            String error;
            var activity = this.Context as Activity;

            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                clientId: "",
                scope: "",
                authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
                redirectUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")
                );

            auth.Completed += async (sender, eventArgs) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated)
                        {
                            await AccountStore.Create().SaveAsync(eventArgs.Account, "FacebookProviderKey");

                            var accessToken = eventArgs.Account.Properties["access_token"].ToString();
                            var expiresIn = Convert.ToDouble(eventArgs.Account.Properties["expires_in"]);
                            var expiryDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(expiresIn);

                            var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email,first_name,last_name,gender,picture"), null, eventArgs.Account);
                            var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                            var obj = JObject.Parse(response.GetResponseText());

                            var id = obj["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                            var name = obj["first_name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                            var surname = obj["last_name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                            var gender = obj["gender"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                            //var email = obj["email"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");

                            Customer.Customers cust = new Customer.Customers();
                            cust.Credentials = new Customer.Credentials();
                            cust.Name = name;
                            cust.Surname = surname;
                            cust.Email = "";
                            cust.MobilePhone = "";
                            cust.DOB = DateTime.Now;
                            cust.Number = "";
                            cust.City = "";
                            cust.Region = "";
                            cust.Country = "";
                            cust.DeviceToken = "sample";
                            cust.Credentials.SecretKey = "";

                            await customerService.AddCustomer(cust);

                            App.SaveToken(cust.Credentials.Token); - **//This is where I am passing the token**

                            App.NavigateToProfile(string.Format(name + surname));


                        }
                        else
                        {
                            App.NavigateToProfile("Invalid Login");
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        error = ex.Message;
                    }
                };
            activity.StartActivity(auth.GetUI(activity));
        }
```

**App.cs**

```
 public App()

 {
        InitializeComponent();


        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
    public static void NavigateToProfile(string message)
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = (new Profile(message));
    }

    static string _Token;
    public static string Token
    {
        get { return _Token; }
    }

    public static void SaveToken(string token)
    {
        _Token = token;
    }
```

AboutPage.cs - I am passing the token in a label just to see if it's passing

```
public partial class About : ContentPage
    {
        private Label _lbltoken;
        public About()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            Appearing += (object s, EventArgs a) => {
                _lbltoken.Text = App.Token;
            };

            string tk = App.Token;

            _lbltoken = new Label()
            {
                FontSize = 20,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                Text = tk,
            };
            var stack = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                Children = { _lbltoken },
            };
            Content = stack;

        }


    }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion. Can't you do the other way around? I mean, writing the service in the PCL project, so that the token can be accessed by all the other projects

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MessagingCenter. 
Messages may be sent as a result like a button click, a system event  or some other incident. Subscribers might be listening in order to change the appearance of the user interface, save data or trigger some other operation.

[More Info](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/)

Comment: Thanks, will try this out

Answer (score 0):

I don't really now if its good idea use static fields in App class. Xamarin access all fields with service locator, `App.Current.[property]` I will suggest you try to change these fields to public

```
string _Token;
public string Token
{
  get { return _Token; }
}

public void SaveToken(string token)
{
  _Token = token;
}
```

and use it with `App.Current.SaveToken(token)` or `App.Current.Token`